# No database selected on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got this code to create a JSON file with the data I have in my database:

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "boxr") or die("Error connecting with the host.");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

$response = array();
$users = array();
$result = mysql_query ($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $gamertag = $row['gamertag'];
    $banned = $row['banned'];

    $users[] = array('gamertag' => $gamertag, 'banned' => $banned);

}

$response['users'] = $users;

$fp = fopen('users.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);

?>
```

The problem is when I run the script it shows the following:

```
No database selected
```

I checked my code twice but I can't figure out why its telling me that.

Comment: MySQL functions are deprecated and should not be used anymore. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the database name with:

```
mysql_select_db ('your_db_name');
```

---

Well you can do it like that:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123") or die("Error connecting with the host.");
mysql_select_db("boxr", $connect);
```

And later, correct it:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))...
```

By:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))...
```

If you are calling the function with the name $sql, you can't later put the name of $result.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_* functions are deprecated but you could change your query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbname.users") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $connect);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db_name : ' . mysql_error());
}
```